# SAS - Determine if group of columns contains any value of a set

Tags: filter, sas, proc-sql, datastep

I have a data set that contains several numbered columns, `Code1, Code2, ... Code12`.  I also have a set of values for those codes `%myCodes = ('ABC','DEF','GHI',etc.)`.

What I want to do is filter so that I include only rows where at least one of the Code1 through Code12 columns contains a value from myCodes.  I realize that I could just do a very long OR condition [e.g. `(Code1 in &myCodes or Code2 in &myCodes or ...)`], but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your columns that you want to select within a macro variable and loop over them all.

```
%let cols    = col1 col2 col3 col4;
%let myCodes = ('ABC','DEF','GHI');

%macro condition;
    %scan(&cols, 1) IN &myCodes

    %do i = 2 %to %sysfunc(countw(&cols));
        OR %scan(&cols, &i) IN &myCodes
    %end;
%mend;

data want;
    set have;
    where %condition;
run;
```

If you look at `%condition`, it has all of your filters:

```
%put %condition;

col1 IN ('ABC','DEF','GHI') OR col2 IN ('ABC','DEF','GHI') OR col3 IN ('ABC','DEF','GHI') OR col4 IN ('ABC','DEF','GHI')
```

Comment: Interesting.  So this is essentially a shorter way of crafting the large OR condition?

Comment: Exactly. It doesn't change the efficiency but it makes it way easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would concatenate col1-12 into a variable then use a regular expression:

```
length long_text $32767 ;
long_text = catx('~', of col:);

found = prxmatch('/(abc|def|ghi)/oi', long_text);
```

Obviously, this requires to rework your list of codes to search for, but I think this pretty efficient until you don't want to identify the variable(s) that contain(s) the code!

Comment: I like the elegance of this one. I'd be curious about how fast it runs in a `where` condition. I have run into situations where `prxmatch` ran pretty slowly, but I also did not use the `o` flag so that may have contributed. `where prxmatch('/(abc|def|ghi)/oi', catx('~', of col:));`

Comment: The PRXMATCH function will automatically /o when the pattern is literal. From Docs:  "Compiling a Perl Regular Expression
If perl-regular-expression is a constant or if it uses the /o option, then the Perl regular expression is compiled once and each use of PRXMATCH reuses the compiled expression. If perl-regular-expression is not a constant and if it does not use the /o option, then the Perl regular expression is recompiled for each call to PRXMATCH."

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you mean by efficient.

In general you will have to test all of the CODEx variables to be sure that none of them contain a code of interest.  So your proposed long expression might be the most efficient it terms of performance.

You could use a code generator (such as a SAS macro) to help you generate the repetitive code.  That would be more efficient for the programmer even if it has no impact on the actual execution time.

You could use an ARRAY to allow you to loop of the set of CODEx variables. That does offer an opportunity to stop once at least one is found which might be more efficient.

```
array code[12];
do index=1 to dim(code) until(found);
   found= code[index] in %mycodes ;
end; 
if found;
```

But there is extra work required to implement the looping so for the cases that do not match it might actually take longer.  Plus you could not use that in a WHERE statement.

Depending on the codes it might be better to loop over the codes in %MYCODES and test if they appear in any of the CODEx variables instead.  You will need to know how many codes in in %MYCODES for this to work.

```
array code[12] ;
array mycodes [3] $3 _temporary_ %mycodes;
do index=1 to dim(mycodes) until(found);
  found = mycodes[index] in code ;
end;
if found;
```

Comment: Efficient may not have been the right word.  Perhaps more elegant would be a better way of putting it?  Or maybe simpler.

Comment: So would the latter way of doing it be better if there are fewer codes in MYCODES than CODEx variables?

Comment: You also might be able to short circuit if you know that the empty code variables are always at the end so that you could also stop when you hit an empty CODEx variable.